# Dynamically add checkboxes to asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add Checkboxes dynamically to webpage

```
            string[] words = masg.Split('~');
            int size = words.Length;
            CheckBox[] cbl = new CheckBox[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                cbl[i] = new CheckBox();
                cbl[i].Text = words[i].ToString();
                this.Controls.Add(cbl[i]);  
               // Response.Write("\n" + words[i]);
            }
```

I am getting error

> **Control 'ctl01' of type 'CheckBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.**

How should I proceed ? What changes to make on aspx page ? Please help.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change it to add in form, because `this` is referencing your Page. and any server control which you are creating programmatic or by adding on page with `runat="server"` should place inside a form tag.

like

```
this.Form.Controls.Add(cbl[i]);
```

or place a placeholder or panel on the form. and than you can add in it

like

```
placeholder1.Controls.Add(cbl[i]);
```

If your .aspx does not contain a form tag, then you should place a form tag there

like

```
<form runat="server" id="form1">

 //Other mark up or server controls.

</form>
```

Comment: . Please help what to do on aspx page.

Comment: @mhasan, then first you should place a form there.

Comment: How can I obtain reference to these checkboxes (to see whether they are checked or not) on a postback to the server?

Comment: @JamesWierzba, you can iterate controls from placeholder1 or this.Form, like `for(var ctrl in this.Form.Controls){ if(ctrl is Checkbox){ var checkbox =  (Checkbox)ctrl; checkbox.IsChecked; } }`

Answer (score 2):

hi you need to add a parent control like Panel on your form and then add your check box controls to that panel

```
string[] words = masg.Split('~');
        int size = words.Length;
        CheckBox[] cbl = new CheckBox[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            cbl[i] = new CheckBox();
            cbl[i].Text = words[i].ToString();
            pnlControls.Controls.Add(cbl[i]); 
           // Response.Write("\n" + words[i]);
        }
```

Add the a panle control in your aspx page :

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlControls" runat="server" >
```