# How to bind an array list values into check boxes in VB.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, vb.net

I have an array list of around 100 names in my code behind file and i'm looking to display these names as check boxes to select by the end user. How can i display them on my ASPX.Page.

Please give me suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? This may be able to help you if you can translate the c# into VB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134641/dynamically-add-checkboxes-to-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use a repeater, then bind to the repeater. This is the only way to do a mutually exclusive radiolist, since the grouping is buggy.
something like:

```
<asp:repeater runat="server" id="rptList">
    <itemTemplate>
       <asp:checkbox runat="server" id="ckBox" text='<%# eval("nameoftextfield")%>' value='<%# eval("nameofvaluefield")%>' />
    </itemTemplate>
 </asp:repeater>
```

then in the code, you can evaluate like this:

```
Public Sub RetrieveValues()
Dim ckBox As CheckBox
    Dim name As String
    Dim value As String

    For Each item As RepeaterItem In Me.rptList.Items
        If item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            ckBox = CType(item.FindControl("ckBox"), CheckBox)

            If ckBox.Checked = True Then
                name = ckBox.Text
                value = ckBox.Attributes("value")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CheckBoxList control and bind the array to it.

Add a CheckBoxList control to the .aspx file.

In the code-behind class for the page, bind the array to the CheckBoxList control.

For more details check this link :
[Displaying an Array as a Group of Checkboxes](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/aspnet-cookbook/0596003781/ch01s06.html)